# Rabbitmqctl usage to delete Queues

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

How to

create/delete exchange,
create/delete Queues 
bind/unbind queues

using rabbitmqctl.

Please suggest me.

I am using rabbitmq on windows.

Answer (score 1):

With `rabbitmqctl`you can't.

You can so that using [Management Command Line Tool](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html)

> The management plugin ships with a command line tool rabbitmqadmin
>   which can perform the same actions as the web-based UI, and which may
>   be more convenient for use when scripting. Note that rabbitmqadmin is
>   just a specialised HTTP client; if you are contemplating invoking
>   rabbitmqadmin from your own program you may want to consider using the
>   HTTP API directly.

Comment: I am using rabbitmq on windows. I dont see rabbitmqadmin as part of sbin directory.. Please let me know how to get rabbitmqadmin for windows..

Comment: @vinodhy have you read the link ? https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html `Obtaining rabbitmqadm` section ?